# Error building vim from source on debian

Tags: python, vim, installation, debian

Hi I am trying to build vim from source with python support. (Eventually want to install YouCompleteMe)

My configure arguments are as follows:

```
 $>./configure --enable-perlinterp \
 --enable-pythoninterp \
 --enable-cscope \
 --enable-gui=gtk2 \
 --with-python-config-dir=$HOME/mypython/lib/python2.7/config \
--enable-rubyinterp \
--enable-luainterp \
-with-features=huge  \
--enable-multibyte\
 --prefix=$HOME/myvim
```

Configuration seems to complete, but when i then run `make` I get the following error [truncated to end]:

```
gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        version.c -o objects/version.o
link.sh: $LINK_AS_NEEDED set to 'yes': invoking linker directly.
  gcc   -Wl,--as-needed     -o vim objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/charset.o objects/crypt.o objects/crypt_zip.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/mark.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o  objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/version.o objects/window.o     objects/if_python.o      objects/netbeans.o  objects/main.o objects/memfile.o    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11   -lm -ltinfo -lnsl   -ldl    -L/home/arenduc1/mypython/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
objects/if_python.o: In function `StringToChars':
if_python.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString'
objects/if_python.o: In function `StringToLine':
if_python.c:(.text+0x7955): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString'
objects/if_python.o: In function `_ConvertFromPyObject':
if_python.c:(.text+0xbbf0): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
link.sh: Linking failed
make[1]: *** [vim] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/arenduc1/source-pkgs/vim/src'
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

Comment: I had the exactly same error when compile vim on CentOS 6.5. No solution has found yet.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined usually means versions mismatch. Ld refers to some header file where there's nothing like `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString' and linking fails. Just read the Docs carefully. It should be written there what libraries accompany your Vim. Debian traditionally is packed with ancient stuff.